# am not getting calendar after clicking textbox in asp.net which uses jquery calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

this was the link which i followed
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/04/jquery-ui-datepickercalendar-example-in.html

```
    <!--dates link-->

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
        });
  </script>


 <script>
```

the problem is calendar is not displayed when clicking a textbox and there is no property called datepicker after a period(.)

```
 <p>From: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
        <p>To: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works like a charm and no problem was found.
look at [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com/defujavose/edit?html,output) to see your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
    $(function () {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    $(function () {
      $("#datepicker1").datepicker();
    });
  </script>

  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>From: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  <p>To: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
</body>
</html>
```